# What is wrong with my lagrange multiplier matlab code?

Tags: matlab

I want to find the two farthest points lying on a closed curve with respect to a line. Lagrange multiplier seems to be do the job. But something is wrong with my code: I have 10 solution points (length(xsol)=10, some are repeated so the picture has only 7) and only two of them are what I want (with red ticks). Why would some points not lie on the curve?

```
syms x y L
g = @(x,y) x^2+2*x*y^2+y^6-1;
h = @(x,y) -4*x+y; % to max or min this such that g=0 is satisfied
gradg = jacobian(g,[x,y]); gradh = jacobian(h,[x,y]);
lagr = gradh - L*gradg;
[L,xsol,ysol]=solve(lagr(1),lagr(2),g);
plot(xsol,ysol,'bo')
```

[image]

What is wrong?

Comment: Because some of the solutions are in the complex plane.  If you only mean to solve over the reals, you can disregard the complex solutions. Also, I count four real solutions that lie on the constraint.

Comment: When I put syms x y real, matlab gives only one solution but it cannot even plot the point.

Comment: I wouldn't restrict the set of numbers in the symbolic engine since the complex solutions are valid solutions (in line with the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra). And the engine apparently decides to parametrize the solution since I guess the uniqueness is lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lagrange multiplier gives local max, local min and also complex solutions. To get the farthest two points, we need one more step: evaluate the function values of all the 'solutions', find the indices with respect to the maximum and the minimum and finally we have the two points.

```
xsolreal=real(double(xsol)); % take the real part for giving accurate results
ysolreal=real(double(ysol));
fnvalue=zeros(1,length(xsol));
for i=1:length(xsol)
    fnvalue(i)=-4*xsolreal(i)+ysolreal(i); % function value of the given line
end
gmax=find(fnvalue == max(fnvalue(:)));
gmin=find(fnvalue == min(fnvalue(:)));
x1=xsolreal(gmax);
y1=ysolreal(gmax);
x2=xsolreal(gmin);
y2=ysolreal(gmin);
```